# Referencing custom google analytics metric on a dashing dashboard

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashing

I have a dashing dashboard set up which I have showing the "ga:activeVisitors' metric. This works fine and I've no problems there. My question is how do I show a different stat that my ga is capturing for example... On one of my GA dashboards I have a widget showing a real time value of another metric. How would I reference that instead of the ga:activeVisitors metric?

my code is as follows:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

# Update these to match your own apps credentials
service_account_email = '[email]' # Email of service account key_file = '[key file path]' # File containing your private key key_secret = 'secret' # Password to unlock private key profile_id = 'profile' # Analytics profile ID.

# Get the Google API client
client = Google::APIClient.new(
:application_name => '[app name]',
:application_version => '0.01'
)

visitors = []

# Load your credentials for the service account
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:token_credential_uri =>  'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
:issuer => service_account_email,
:signing_key => key)

# Start the scheduler
SCHEDULER.every '1s', :first_in => 0 do

# Request a token for our service account
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

# Get the analytics API
analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')

# Execute the query
response = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get,   :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + profile_id,
'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
})

visitors << { x: Time.now.to_i, y: response.data.rows }

# Update the dashboard
send_event('visitor_count_real_time', points: visitors)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To access real time data you need to use the [Real-time api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/).

the real time api has a different set of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) then the core reporting api you will need to use those. which it looks like you are `ga:activeVisitors`

> The Real Time Reporting API is currently available as a developer
>   preview in limited beta. If you're interested in signing up,  [request
>   access](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform) to the beta.

it normally takes 24 hours to get access you will not hear anything from google you should just try and make a request.

I am not a ruby programmer but your code:   `analytics.data.realtime.get`  looks correct to me.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors my problem is simply grabbing the correct stat I want from one of my dashboards. The API seems to be great for getting at default stats, but not so for custom ones that have been built.

Comment: Your not going to get anything custom off the website.  Your going to have to build it all manually.

Answer (score -2):

On the following website you will find GA Queries Examples:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries

Maybe it helps you?

Comment: And with the Query-Explorer you can test your queries before you use them in the dashing Google Analytics Widget:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.